# Create a button in flutter with image in background

Tags: flutter, button, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a `Button` in Flutter, that has an image in the background and Containers above, but i want the `Container` to have a individual shape. The image below is just an example. I want to make a couple of these buttons.

I figured, that I might want to use a `Stack` and a `GestureDetector` to achieve this, but how am I going to "reshape" the orange and grey Containers above the image?

I would really appreciate a hint on how to achieve this. Thank you in advange guys .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [Ink](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html) widget like this with container

```
Container(
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Ink(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(
              'images/car_poster.png',
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          onTap: () {},
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'title',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah you are right you have to use stack and gesture detector but also you need to use Custom Paint flutter widget in order to draw the orange and grey shape if you want to know how to draw shapes in flutter  visit this site
[Drawing shapes in Flutter with CustomPaint and Shape Maker](https://blog.logrocket.com/drawing-shapes-in-flutter-with-custompaint-and-shape-maker/)

Comment: Yesss thats what i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code hope it help to you

```
Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png',
              ),
            ),
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          ),
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('Pressed');
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
```

Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Here is an example:

```
    Container(
        height: 200,
        width: 300,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Material(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  //Here you can call your own animation for animate the Image
                },
                // Add Your Own Image
                child: Image.network(
                  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/75973/pexels-photo-75973.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
                  height: 200,
                  width: 300,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make any widget clickable, wrap it with a InkWell widget

```
InkWell(
    onTap: () {
    toggle();
    },
    child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage( 
       Image: NetworkImage(ImageURL)    //or AssetImage(ImageURL)
    BoxFit.Cover)),
```